# Resx files for other languages are not being populated on build

Tags: multilingual-app-toolkit

I have recently added the Multilingual App Toolkit to our projects. There are several assemblies which are dlls and exes which have resx files and one dll that is for global resources.

Each assembly has a Locales and MultilingualResources directories. Locales stores Resources.resx and Resources.XXX.resx files while the MultilingualResources stores the xlf files. Generate machine translations works and populates the xlf files.

However I have only been able to get the Resources.XXX.resx files of our global resources to be populated. I have tried doing complete rebuilds and manually setting state of all resource strings to translated, but the other assembly Resources.XXX.resx files do not get populated.

How can I force Multilingual App Toolkit to populate the Resources.XXX.resx files. Also does populating the other Resources.XXX.resx files depend on the state of a translation in xlf files?

We are using version 4.0.1605.0.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this error with one project not updating the Resources.XXX.resx files with new or updated translations from the .xlf file.

It turned out the issue was that project renames don't completely propagate through the .xlf files. When we renamed the project from OldName to NewName, the group id in the .xlf files was correctly changed to "NEWNAME/LOCALES/RESOURCES.RESX". The the original element in the header was not changed and was still "OLDNAME/LOCALES/RESOURCES.RESX"

We used a text editor to manually change value for "original" to the new project name for every .xlf file and the problem was solved.